# Condensing a for-loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have the following code in `R`

```
library(mvtnorm)

m = matrix(rnorm(2000000),nrow=200)
A = matrix(rnorm(40000),ncol=200)
A = A%*%t(A)
C = array(A,c(200,200,10000))

B = 10000
S = 100

postpred = array(NA,c(200,S,B))
for(i in 1:B){
    postpred[,,i] = t(rmvnorm(S,m[,i],C[,,i],method="svd"))
}
```

but this code is extremely slow because I have to loop 10,000 times while also simulating from the multivariate normal 100 times and `m` and `C` can be very large as well. So what I would like to do is be able to calculate `postpred` outside of a loop.  I have tried using the apply function but to no avail.  Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since each of your calls to `rmvnorm` within the loop takes a different mean and covariance matrix, you're still going to need to call the function 10,000 times, regardless of whether you do so in a loop or with `apply`. Since you've already pre-allocated `postpred` my guess is you won't get that much of a speedup by switching to `apply`. Probably the reason your code is slow is that you're trying to draw a total of 200 million values from 10,000 different multivariate normal distributions.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out that *apply* (and similar functions) won't help you much in your case, and they are right.

For what it is worth, I checked whether your would have a gain of performance by compiling your code. Here is a little benchmark that I made with your problem (I reduced the size of the matrices, because otherwise I cannot run them):

```
library(mvtnorm)

func = function()
{ 
  m = matrix(rnorm(200000),nrow=100)
  A = matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol=100)
  A = A%*%t(A)
  C = array(A,c(100,100,1000))

  B = 1000
  S = 10

  postpred = array(NA,c(1000,S,B))
  for(i in 1:B){
    postpred[,,i] = t(rmvnorm(S,m[,i],C[,,i],method="svd"))
  }
}

require(compiler)
func_compiled <- cmpfun(func)

require(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(func_compiled(), func(), times=10) # grab a coffee, this takes some time
```

The results show that compiling won't give you any advantage:

```
Unit: seconds
                 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 slow_func_compiled() 9.938632 10.12269 10.18237 10.48215 15.43299    10
          slow_func() 9.969320 10.07676 10.21916 15.44664 15.66109    10
```

(this could have been expected, as the library `mvtnorm` should be already compiled)

Overall, you have only two ways left to optimize your code in R:

1. use smaller numbers (if acceptable)
2. parallelize your code

Answer (score 0):

As Josillber says, <strike>vectorisation</strike> (*apply family of functions*) ain't going to do much for you, it really is a bit of an R myth that it gives significant speed improvements.

Suggest you look at parallel options, there are parallel mcapply and snow packages. Read more here http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

Comment: I think you meant to say "apply" rather than "vectorization". The former often doesn't speed things up, the latter does.